# 502 error from Gradle Wrapper downloading from Artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm having trouble getting Gradle wrapper to download the -bin.zip file from an Artifactory instance.  I'd like to distribute my corporate-modified (added init scripts) version of Gradle via our Artifactory artifact manager, but receive a 502 error from the Artifactory server.  Unfortuantely, the Artifactory server has nothing useful in its logs for this request.  I have validated that my browser can successfully and fully download the file `http://testlab3:8081/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/gradle/gradle/1.4/gradle-1.4-bin.zip` if I enter it into the location bar.

Here's the relevant closure:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    distributionUrl = 'http://testlab3:8081/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/gradle/gradle/1.4/gradle-1.4-bin.zip'
}
```

Then I execute

```
$gradle wrapper
```

And here's the trace I'm getting when I try to use the wrapper:

```
c:\Development\Intellij\projectName>gradlew tasks
Downloading http://testlab3:8081/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/gradle/g
radle/1.4/gradle-1.4-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response co
de: 502 for URL: http://testlab3:8081/artifactory/simple/ext-release-local/gra
dle/gradle/1.4/gradle-1.4-bin.zip
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1612)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:63)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:49)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:51)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best bet is that your Gradle proxy configuration is missing or incorrect (e.g. no `http.nonProxyHosts` set). You can learn more about Gradle proxy configuration in the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy).

PS: Please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org. That just creates more work for everyone.